# I am having trouble writing my SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have an sql query like this...

```
SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
       (SELECT ifnull(sum(total), 0) 
          FROM invoice i
         WHERE i.client = c.clientid AND i.isdeleted = 0) -
       (SELECT ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) 
          FROM payment p
         INNER JOIN invoice i ON p.invoice = i.invoiceid
         WHERE i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) as balance, 
        CASE c.isactive+0 WHEN '1' THEN 'Stop'
                                   ELSE 'Start' END as Active
FROM client c
ORDER BY clientname
```

This works fine with no errors, but notice this part....

```
(SELECT ifnull(sum(total), 0) 
          FROM invoice i
         WHERE i.client = c.clientid AND i.isdeleted = 0) -(SELECT ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) 
   FROM payment p
  INNER JOIN invoice i ON p.invoice = i.invoiceid
  WHERE i.client = c.clientid AND i.isdeleted = 0) as balance
```

I wrote a PHP script...

```
if($remaining < 0){
    $remaining = $row['total'];
}else{
    $remaining = $remaining + $row['total'];
}
```

What I am trying to do is incorporate what I wrote in my PHP to my SQL query, but I have never wrote an SQL query with if statements before (if they are allowed). How would incorporate my PHP script to my SQL query? Any suggestions?

Comment: from a performance perspective, wouldn't it make sense to get the data from the database and do the validation with `PHP`?

Comment: I have considered that, the problem with that is the query I have returns a list of clients and they have individual remaining balances, so for each client I would have to get their id's and run the php script for each client.

Comment: I don't see how `$remaining` and `$row['total']` relate to the query...

Comment: oh crap...your right, I updated my question sum(total) is $row['total']

Comment: OK, and how do you get to $remaining?

Comment: @hol - Yeah, cause otherwise this looks completely sane, query wise (although needed better formatting).

Answer (score 2):

There is no `if`, but there is `case` which allows you to do pretty much the same. You already use a `case` in your query, so I think you know how it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your result and use it. Make sure total and remaining is part of your result.

```
SELECT tt.clientid, tt.clientname, tt.billingdate, tt.total, tt.remaining, tt.active 
  FROM (
            ... here goes all of your select but the the order by 
       ) tt
ORDER BY tt.clientid
```

With that construct you could do what you do in PHP

```
SELECT tt.clientid, tt.clientname, tt.billingdate, tt.total, tt.active,
       CASE WHEN tt.remaining < 0 then tt.total
                                  else tt.remaining - tt.total
            END as remaining
  FROM (
            ... here goes all of your select make sure you select a total and a remaining
       ) tt
ORDER BY tt.clientid
```

So what you do is to create a temporary view actually. Not sure about your data model but I think that would look like this

```
SELECT tt.clientid, tt.clientname, tt.billingdate, tt.total, tt.active,
       CASE WHEN tt.remaining < 0 then tt.total
                                  else tt.remaining - tt.total
            END as remaining
 FROM (
    SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
       (SELECT ifnull(sum(total), 0) 
          FROM invoice i
         WHERE i.client = c.clientid AND i.isdeleted = 0) as total,
       (SELECT ifnull(sum(total), 0) 
          FROM invoice i
         WHERE i.client = c.clientid AND i.isdeleted = 0) -
       (SELECT ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) 
          FROM payment p
         INNER JOIN invoice i ON p.invoice = i.invoiceid
         WHERE i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) as remaining, 
        CASE c.isactive+0 WHEN '1' THEN 'Stop'
                                   ELSE 'Start' END as Active
      FROM client c
      ) TT
ORDER BY clientname
```